# PHP Array to JSON in this format as requested

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I need to make a php array from a mysql request, and in a loop pass into a JSON.

My sql is like this below:

```
$arDados = array();
$result = $conexao->sql("SELECT * FROM sys_fabrica WHERE fl_ativo = 1 ORDER BY tl_fabrica");    
while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $cd_fabrica = $dados['cd_fabrica'];
    $tl_fabrica = $dados['tl_fabrica'];
    $tl_razao = $dados['tl_razao'];
    
    $totalValorAno = retornaValorTotalAnoPecas($ano, $cd_fabrica);
    $metaFaturamentoAnual = retornaMetaFaturamentoAnual($ano, $cd_fabrica);
    $percentMetaFaturamentoAnual = number_format(($totalValorAno * 100) / $metaFaturamentoAnual, 0, ',', '.');
    if($percentMetaFaturamentoAnual < 50){
        $classeProgressFaturamento = "danger";
    } else if($percentMetaFaturamentoAnual < 90){
        $classeProgressFaturamento = "warning";
    } else {
        $classeProgressFaturamento = "success";
    }
    
    $arrayDados[]      = array(
        fabrica => $tl_fabrica, 
        value => abs($percentMetaFaturamentoAnual),
        full => 100,
        columnSettings => array(
            fillOpacity => 1,
            fill => "am5.color(KTUtil.getCssVariableValue('--bs-$classeProgressFaturamento'))";
        )
    ); 
}
$arrayDados = json_encode($arrayDados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $arrayDados;
```

And this is the data I need to pass into thee graphics (AMCharts).

```
// Data
                var data = [
                    {
                        fabrica: "Fabrica",
                        value: 80,
                        full: 100,
                        columnSettings: {
                            fillOpacity: 1,
                            fill: am5.color(KTUtil.getCssVariableValue('--bs-info')),
                        },
                    }
                ];
```

Comment: Q: Is json_encode() not working for you?  What exactly is the problem/question?  Q: Why is the arran and the JSON the same variable name?  Why not `$jsonDados = json_encode($arrayDados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`?

Comment: That data is not valid Json, though it looks a little like Json

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` hasn't existed since PHP 5. Please do not use it

Comment: Why isn't the `fill` value double quote wrapped?  Why aren't your php array keys wrapped in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the help.
This is how I solved.

I worked it out using XML and pushing data into js object.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?=SITE_PATH?>/studio/assets/ajax/index_data_grafico_meta_ano.php?ano=<?=$ano?>&codFabrica=<?=$codFabrica?>",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                var data = [];
                $(xml).find('item').each(function(index){
                    var codFabrica = $(this).find('codigo').text();
                    var fantasia = $(this).find('fantasia').text();
                    var razao = $(this).find('razao').text();
                    var meta = $(this).find('meta').text();
                    var classe = $(this).find('classe').text();
                    
                    var colorGraph = KTUtil.getCssVariableValue('--bs-'+classe);
                    colorGraph = am5.color(colorGraph);
                    
                    var columnSettings = {};
                    columnSettings = {
                        fillOpacity: 1,
                        fill: colorGraph
                    }
                    
                    data.push({
                        fabrica : fantasia,
                        value: meta,
                        full: 100,
                        columnSettings: columnSettings
                    });
                });
```